# JavaScript reduce() method behavior with array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the next array of arrays:

```
[ 
  [ {inner: {text: ["name"]}}, {inner: {text: ["height"]}}, {inner: {text: ["country"]}} ],
  [
    [ {text: ["Kilimanjaro"]}, {text: ["5895"]}, {text: ["Tanzania"]} ],
    [ {text: ["Everest"]}, {text: ["8848"]}, {text: ["Nepal"]} ],
    [ {text: ["Mount Fuji"]}, {text: ["3776"]}, {text: ["Japan"]} ],
    [ {text: ["Mont Blanc"]}, {text: ["4808"]}, {text: ["Italy/France"]} ],
    [ {text: ["Vaalserberg"]}, {text: ["323"]}, {text: ["Netherlands"]} ],
    [ {text: ["Denali"]}, {text: ["6168"]}, {text: ["United States"]} ],
    [ {text: ["Popocatepetl"]}, {text: ["5465"]}, {text: ["Mexico"]} ],
  ]
]
```

"inner" and "text" are instances of 2 constructors. Pretty simple so far.

And I have the next function to work with that array:

```
function rowHeights(rows) {
  return rows.map(function(row) {
    return row.reduce(function(max, cell) {
      return Math.max(max, cell.minHeight());
    }, 0);
  });
}
```

`minHeight()` just returns length of array + 1, if called from "inner". Or just length of array, if called from "text".

Let me show you how does I expect this function to work:

```
rows[ 
  row[0][ {inner: {text: ["name"]}}, {inner: {text: ["height"]}}, {inner: {text: ["country"]}} ],
  row[1][
    reduce[0][ {text: ["Kilimanjaro"]}, {text: ["5895"]}, {text: ["Tanzania"]} ],
    reduce[1][ {text: ["Everest"]}, {text: ["8848"]}, {text: ["Nepal"]} ],
    reduce[2][ {text: ["Mount Fuji"]}, {text: ["3776"]}, {text: ["Japan"]} ],
    and so on...[ {text: ["Mont Blanc"]}, {text: ["4808"]}, {text: ["Italy/France"]} ],
    [ {text: ["Vaalserberg"]}, {text: ["323"]}, {text: ["Netherlands"]} ],
    [ {text: ["Denali"]}, {text: ["6168"]}, {text: ["United States"]} ],
    [ {text: ["Popocatepetl"]}, {text: ["5465"]}, {text: ["Mexico"]} ],
  ]
]
```

And this is how it actually works:

```
rows[ 
  row[0][ {inner: {text: ["name"]}}, {inner: {text: ["height"]}}, {inner: {text: ["country"]}} ],
  row[1][
    [reduce[0] {text: ["Kilimanjaro"]},reduce[1] {text: ["5895"]},reduce[2] {text: ["Tanzania"]} ],
    [reduce[0] {text: ["Everest"]},reduce[1] {text: ["8848"]},reduce[2] {text: ["Nepal"]} ],
    [and so on... {text: ["Mount Fuji"]}, {text: ["3776"]}, {text: ["Japan"]} ],
    [ {text: ["Mont Blanc"]}, {text: ["4808"]}, {text: ["Italy/France"]} ],
    [ {text: ["Vaalserberg"]}, {text: ["323"]}, {text: ["Netherlands"]} ],
    [ {text: ["Denali"]}, {text: ["6168"]}, {text: ["United States"]} ],
    [ {text: ["Popocatepetl"]}, {text: ["5465"]}, {text: ["Mexico"]} ],
  ]
]
```

The result of `rowHeights` is:

```
[2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

I understand the first element. It compares 3 elements of first array and returns 2.

My question appears when it begins to work with the second array.

What do I understand wrong about `reduce()` and `rowHeights()`?

P.S. This is an example from the Eloquent Javascript 2nd edition book. If you want to see full code, please click [here](https://eloquentjavascript.net/2nd_edition/06_object.html#h_36C2FHHi44).

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Would replacing `row.reduce` with `row.flat().reduce` solve your issue?

Comment: NB: I think the whole constructor thing and `minHeight` method is a complexity to your question which you should better remove, I don't feel it is relevant to the issue you have. Try to simplify the question to the bare minimum, maybe with just arrays of integers.

Comment: @trincot no, I don't want to change anything, I just want to understand why does it work that way

Comment: @trincot let's pretend in row[1] we have a next array [1, 2, 3]. We apply the reduce() method with basic summing function to row[1] and it will return 6 to us. Now what will happen if we replace these numbers with arrays?

Comment: Then `cell` will be that nested array. I am surprised that ´cell.minHeight()` does not return an error in that case, unless you tell me those nested arrays are also constructed/customised.

Comment: @trincot I expect it to begin sum the arrays, but the rowHeights() tells me that it would begin to enter in these arrays and sum their elements. Can I post here a link to jsbin, so you can get the full view?

Comment: I would prefer a link to documentation on `rowHeights`/`minHeights`, or else its implementation code.

Comment: @trincot sure. It's here: https://eloquentjavascript.net/2nd_edition/06_object.html#h_36C2FHHi44

Comment: With a quick glance, I see that the tutorial code is intended to work on a 2D array (rows & columns), while you seem to have split the "data"-rows from the "header" row, and put the data rows in a deeper level. This makes your table 3D, and the functions described on that page, just are not designed for that. I don't really feel like debugging... I am sure you could do this yourself and just inspect the variables when you loop. I just wonder why you would use those functions with data that is not structured as it is supposed to be.

Comment: @trincot I just do everything as tutorials says. Everything works properly, but my problem is - I don't know why.

Comment: I disagree. The tutorial describes arrays where the header row is a sibling to the other data rows, not like you have it in your input array. See where it says `return [headers].concat(body);`. That gives a 2D array, not 3D.

Comment: @trincot oh god, haha, you're right. I accidently made it 3D. I've interpreted concat() method wrong in the function that creates that array of arrays. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I think this question can be closed or deleted, because no-one searching for the behaviour of `concat` would arrive here with a search. The problem statement is quite unrelated to it.